# Add inline ImageBackground to Text (Image inside Text component) -React-native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use `ImageBackground` inside `Text`, the `ImageBackground` has also a text inside it.
here is my code:

```js
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.verseText}>
        {props.verseText}
        <ImageBackground
          source={require('Resources/verseNumber.png')}
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={styles.verseNumber}
          imageStyle={styles.verseImage}>
          <Text>{props.verseNumber}</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default QuranVerseComponent;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: height * 0.25,
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    padding: 20,
    // justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderBottomWidth: 3,
  },
  verseNumber: {
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginRight: 8,
  },
  verseImage: {
    tintColor: '#c48323',
  },
  verseText: {
    fontSize: commonStyle.FONT_SIZE_H1,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    writingDirection: 'rtl',
  },
});
```

Android gives this error:

[image]

IOS has this display:

[image]

you can see the image is not at the end of text plus normally there is a number inside the image, we get a placeholder, but i think this was solved in latest releases as a saw an issue about it.

react-native: 0.60.6

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

```js
 render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          source={assets.splashBg}
          style={styles.splash}
          resizeMode="stretch"
        />
        <Image source={assets.splashLogo} style={styles.splashBg} />
        <View style={styles.footerView}>
          <Text style={[styles.splashFooter]}>copyright text here</Text>
          <Text style={[styles.splashFooter, styles.b30]}>
            Your text here
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

```css
   

container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignContent: 'center',
  },
  splash: {
    width,
    height,
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  splashBg: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: -120,
    width: '110%',
    height: height,
  },
  footerView: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  splashFooter: {
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 17,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 50,
  },
 b30: {
    bottom: 30,
  },
```

Salam m B. Mohammad

you can not directly add text in  you must be used  inside 
like this

Comment: Wa alaikom salam Nasir, you can use `Image` inside text, i have tested it. the problem is with `ImageBackground` component.